# image position swapping in a image strip through jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, strip

Not sure that i had structured the question right ,as i am not sure about the terminologies ,being new to web development. I have a page where there are four images in separate div, inside a parent div set as a strip of images with separate links.
I want to swap their positions , say every 2 min through jquery may be randomly or in a cyclic order.

```
<div class="featurelisting-images">

     <div class="fl-list" id="fl1">
         <a href="/xyz.html" alt="xyz" title="xyz">
         <img src="/uploads/photo_1239.jpg"  title="xyz" alt="xyz" class=""/></a>                    
         <p class="title"><a href="/xyz.html" alt="xyz" title="xyz">xyz</a></p>
     </div>

     <div class="fl-list"    id="fl2">            
          <a href="/abc.html" alt="abc" title="abc">
          <img src="/uploads/photo_1357.jpg"  title="abc" alt="abc" class=""/></a>                    
          <p class="title"><a href="/abc.html" alt="abc" title="abc">abc</a></p>
     </div>

          // two more div elements like this...

</div>
```

I have got very limited knowledge of Jquery and am looking for a script to work for me. I tried Google it , but didn't got the right solution, may be because of wrong search terminology for this function. Tried some thing, but nothing worked.( [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/ejTSG/2/) )
I am trying using insert element in Jquery than changing all the attributes for each div element.

Comment: It should only show one picture and it should be changed periodically?

Comment: @Kir Read my comments in the answer. I wanted it to be in a moving strip. see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/ejTSG/9/).
Anyway thanks , i didn't saw your comment. issue has been solved. replied hoping that it may of use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the items in a single line using `float:left`

After every two seconds, move the first one to the end.

You can find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/fZmk6/1/).

Please correct me if I am wrong or you want something else.

Comment: what i want is to have a strip of four div containing images and links, which keep changing their positions in the same strip at certain time interval just like a flash image moving strip, just to get some attention from the viewer.
Issue here is that i wan to move the whole dev element, than just image. and i thought that there would be some better soln, than changing all the attributes values one by one.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. However this is not working in my example. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijatyatewari/ejTSG/7/)
I have copied the function, set float but can't see elements move.

I have copied the class & id names ,js and css as such.

Comment: Please use id instead of class for outer items div.

Comment: oh!!! thanks Sasidhar. I got it working now!!
both of ur examples wore great!!! can u give me any link or bit explanation for naming this items id and item nos id child concept.
I am sure i can use it later in multiple ways if i know the thing. Is it jquery exclusive or plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function do(){  
     var divs =  $(".featurelisting-image").children();
     var first_href = divs[0].children[0].href;
     var first_src = divs[0].children[1].src;
     var first_second_href = divs[0].children[1].children[0].href;
     var first_inner = divs[0].children[1].children[0].innerHTML;
     for(var i = 1;i< divs.length;i++){
         divs[i-1].children[0].href = divs[i].children[0].href;
         divs[i-1].children[1].src = divs[i].children[1].src;
         divs[i-1].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = divs[i].children[1].children[0].innerHTML
     }
     divs[divs.length-1].children[0].href = first_href;
     divs[divs.length-1].children[1].src = first_.src;
     divs[divs.length-1].children[1].children[0].innerHTML = first_inner;

  }
</script>
```

you can add this functions to a timer or a button click event...i haven't changed all the attributes but i guess you get the idea...

Comment: Thanks for the answer i guess this will work but by ur code,the only solution is to change the attributes.
is there no way to exchange the div elements as whole inside the parent element, as they are identical.